# how to limit the retrieve data by 30 and the other 30 will be on the next page of the pdf

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

i want to limit the retrieved data by 30 and i want the other 30 to be on the next page of the pdf.. its my first time to use mpdf..

my controller

```
public function print_rel(){
    //die();

    $data['rec'] = $this->home_model->get_latest_data();
    //print_r($data['rec']);die();
    $html = $this->load->view('print_rel',$data, true);
    $this->load->library('pdf');
    $pdf = $this->pdf->load();

    $pdf->AddPage('P', // L - landscape, P - portrait
    '', '', '', '',
    10, // margin_left
    10, // margin right
    40, // margin top
    0, // margin bottom
    14, // margin header
    12);  
    $pdf->WriteHTML($html);

    $pdf->Output();
}
```

my view page

```
<?php $i='1' ; $total = ''; foreach ($rec->result_array() as $key){    ?>
<tr>

    <td  class="centerthis"><?php echo "$i"; ?></td>
    <td  class="centerthis"><?php $date = new DateTime($key['date_reg']); echo $date->format('m-d-Y');?></td>
    <td  class="centerthis"><?php echo $key['lname'] ?></td>    
    <td  class="centerthis"><?php echo $key['fname'] ?></td>
    <td  class="centerthis"><?php echo $key['mi'] ?></td>
    <td  class="centerthis"><?php $date = new DateTime($key['bdate']); echo $date->format('m-d-Y');  ?></td>
    <td  class="centerthis"><?php echo $key['amount'] ?></td>
```

Comment: Just use the limit function 40 then 40,80 for query for second page. Or just get all and use a foreach to add a new page after every 40.

Comment: can you give me an example of foreach to add a new page

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: i want data to be in the next page of the pdf when after generated

Comment: https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-breaks.html